# HttpClient requests ssl website, but cannot get cookie in uwp

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-store-apps, httpclient

I'm using httpclient to request a ssl(https://) site. But I note that even if I can get response from that site, but the site still hasn't set cookie in my local. So, I cannot read cookie from `filter.CookieManager.GetCookies()`.

I guess that's due to I have not add certificate when posting data.

I done another testing, I used webview to open this site, then I can get cookies by `CookieManager.GetCookies`.

So, my question is how I can use httpclient to request "https://" site and make it write cookie in my local.

Comment: You might wanna look at the documentation from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) and also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx) for cookies from response.

Comment: @Ahmar Yep. You're right. I can get cookie from `response.headers`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies(v=vs.110).aspx) for the cookies from response. There is also a working example available.